# Cannot create connection in Azure Data Factory due to access issue

Tags: connection, roles, azure-data-factory, owner

I was given Owner access of an Azure data factory resource. I have to copy a csv from Blob Storage to Azure Table. While creating a copy data pipeline, I cannot create a connection to that csv file. A similar pipeline was successfully working in my free subscription.
I also have owner access of the Blob Storage. Even when I press test connection, it returns "connection successful"

The error that I get is:
The client  with object id  does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/write' over scope .

I have added  in place of different ids in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the error says Write, makes me think that the issue is maybe with the Azure Table resource's permissions. These kind of errors are easy to troubleshoot now, because in the graphical interface you can click the Check Connection button.

Try going to the dataset you've created for this csv file, and click on Preview Data. If it shows data, then the problem is not in the connection to the csv file, and most likely it is with Azure Table.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually I am using the graphical interface and connection is successful when I am trying to create the pipeline. The Preview Data option is available once i establish a connection with the blob service. The error is thrown when i press Finish button after filling out necessary details for a new connection

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying, please refer to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage

Comment: Can you help me out what permissions do I need in order to create connections and copy data from blob to azure table?
I think the whole problem is because of some authorization problem.
the blob and table are in one storage account which is in the same resource group as the data factory.

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem with the roles. To create child objects in Data Factory web tool, one needs the "Data Factory Contributor" role for the whole resource group, not just for the resource itself.

Comment: Thanks, exactly my issue.